# Multiple dataframe arguments to an R function

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm new to R and am writing a library of functions all of which act on a set of 6 linked dataframes. I'd like to avoid having each function have to be called explicitly with the names of the dataframes, e.g. foo(df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,df6, otherargs....). But to do this I need to be able to set default names for the dataframe argument names in the function like:
function(df1=dataframename1.....)
 which I can't get to work, or access the dataframes in the global environment from within my functions which just seems wrong. What is the correct "R-ish" way of dealing with this?

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail and some minimal example code to demonstrate what exactly you're trying to do? (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for ideas)

Comment: just write your functions to accept an argument that is a vector of df names. then you only need specify df names once. I can write out a complete answer if you are unclear on my meaning

Comment: and/or supply your dfs as a list to your functions

Comment: Please [post a repo of your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).  Most likely there is an "`R`" way to approach your problem that will be easier than having to pass 6 data frames to a function.

Comment: See, e.g., [How do I make a list of data frames?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17499013/903061) for tips. Without changing your function you could use `do.call(foo, args = c(list_of_data_frames, otherargs))`, but it might be best to write your function to expect a list of data frames as the input.